# Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I'm aware there are solutions there on this subject, but i have test this on a test page and works correctly. Basically its a feedback form on a receipt page, if the user logs in again and makes a payment, it doesnt see the form a second time.
I did this by putting a hiddden field in the DOM, and switching the value from "Y" to "N" in the VB code behind, this all works fine on the test page. But when I code it in the application, it gives me a the error "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null**". I though at first that the javascript was trying to read the dom, when it hadnt actually rendered yet, so i switched the javascript to the bottom of the page, and even put a timer on it to make sure everything is loaded, still the same result. I cant understand why its doing it in one app, and not the other.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidfeedback" Value="N" runat ="server" />
```

Javascript:

```
//Modal window appears and fades in after 5 secsonds
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var getSessionValue = $('#hidfeedback').val();
            if (document.getElementById('hidfeedback').value === "N") {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: Without sounding condescending are you getting the right ID from the hidfeedback element? When the page is displayed the id for server elements are changed, get the elements client ID.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("<%=hidfeedback.ClientID%>")`. The ID may be being generated by the server. Either way, an element with the ID `hidfeedback` definitely doesn't exist on the page

Comment: try this `<asp:HiddenField ID="hidfeedback" Value="N" runat ="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />`. ClientIDMode="Static" will not the change ID at runtime. So your hidden elements ID will remain unchanged

Comment: @Malcor you dont sound condescending mate, I should of thought of this, face palm, thanks a mil

Comment: JSantosh RGraham Malcor thanks for your time ClientID = stati,c worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var getSessionValue = $('#hidfeedback').val();
```

By

```
var getSessionValue = $('[id*=hidfeedback]').val();
```

**EDIT**

This solution is applicable for all controls in any container. sometime people gets confused with `$(['id$=xyz'])` and `$(['id*=xyz'])`. First one will not work in your control's container is like `GridView` `Repeater` etc.

To make thing even more clear [have a look of selectors here.](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mate, realised straight away when i read the comments, thanks for your time

Comment: i just added a property to the ASP control ClientID = static, thanks for your input tho :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the id in that way, ASP.NET change the objects IDs when render them to client. you should use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hidfeedback.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Thanks mate, realised straight away when i read the comments, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

The client side IDs of controls are different from server side IDs in `asp.net`. Some extra characters get appended before the ID. The best solution is to set `class` to your controls and access them in `jquery` with class selector.

Try the following solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var getSessionValue = $("[id$='hidfeedback']").val();
        if ($("[id$='hidfeedback']").val() === "N") {
            $("[id$='myModal']").modal("show");
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, realised straight away when i read the comments, thanks for your time

Comment: Hey, this is not permanent solution. Suppose I have control in Gridview that has id as `btnMe` then that button will be rendered as something like `grd_btnMe_1` so here `Attribute Ends with selector` will not work that's why I used `Attribute Contains Selector` in my answer.

Comment: the rendered id always add extra charachters as prefix to your id. So there won't be any problem with this approach

Comment: set `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` and see what it renders :)